# How much memory is needed to be reserved for arm64 ATF?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, arm64, u-boot

I am seeing that the Linux is only able to use 384 MiB out of 512 MiB memory. Changing DTS doesn't help. Seems like the U-Boot is reserving 128 MiB for some reason.
Why does ATF (ARM trusted firmware) need 128 MiB of reserved memory?
Does ATF run always run parallel to Linux?
How much is ideal memory partition?

Comment: You need to provide details instead of vague summations. What memory report are you "*seeing*"? What node properties did you change in a DTS? "*Seems like the u-boot ...*" -- Based on what evidence? Or is that just a WAG?

Comment: Based on cat /proc/meminfo, I know that hte linux has 128MiB less memory than is physcially in the RAM. I looked into the optee source conf.mk and it reserved 61MiB and the uboot reserves the other part of 128MiB. I changed the @memory node and it didn't work. I don't know what a 'WAG' is.

Comment: Trusted firmware provides routines for reset and poweroff (PSCI). So its normal that some memory has to be reserved at runtime. You can use TF-A to launch OP-TEE and this may require additional memory. You will have to analyze your TF-A build to understand how much memory is really needed.

Comment: I have been looking around the sources for the the right information but I did not see why it needs so much memory. Just that it reserves a lot of memory.

Answer (score 0):

After much reading of the code, I found the following:

The answer to this depends on the OP-TEE implementation. The ATF / TF-A requires 1MiB of DDR space to be reserved. Now the tricky part is  the OPTEE.
OPTEE needs some memory to be reserved for its runtime. This is allocated for 62 MiB but can be less. OPTEE needs another 2 MiB for its base image.
If you have no need for OPTEE and do not use a trust root, you can reduce this memory required to just 2 MiB. This is entirely within OPTEE build and source.
The next part is u-boot. you boot has a starting base address which is 128MiB into the memory. If you are not having optee, you can pull back the base address to a starting point around 2MiB boundary and allocate the rest of the memory to linux.

However, if your SoC also has an arm microcontroller, it needs some memory reserved for itself. This is the other 64MiB missing from linux kernel.

1 MiB ATF

1 MiB OPTEE core image

62 MiB of OPTEE runtime space.

64 MiB arm mcu reserved space.

As it turns out this is implementation and SoC specific. Some SoC's access the MCU through the trust zone and others use shared memory from within linux memory. I'm out my depth here.